Return Output from Function on Multiple Lines
I've tried to figure this out on my own, but I'm coming to a dead end. I'm trying to return a string from a function that I created that references amounts derived from a pandas dataframe that was created earlier in the function, and I want each variable reference to be shown as it's own line as the output:
net_winnings = all_invest_df['Payout'].sum()-all_invest_df['Investment'].sum()

return f"""Invested Amount: {all_invest_df['Investment'].sum()}
           Payout Amount: {all_invest_df['Payout'].sum()}
           Net Winnings: {net_winnings}"""
                                              

What I want to see is:
Invested Amount: xxxxx
Payout Amount: xxxxx
Net Winnings: xxxxx
But this is my current output:
'Invested Amount: 20680\n               Payout Amount: 25442.31574810885\n               Net Winnings: 4762.315748108849'
Any ideas for out to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks.

You need to explicitly print() that string, so that the newline characters actually produce new lines.  You appear to have typed the function call at the Python interactive prompt, which gives you the repr() of the string rather than the string itself.

You shared a return statement, but it's not inside a function (or you left that off). It's also unclear how you are printing this value to the screen - it seems likely that you're looking at the string representation in an interactive Python session, instead of printing the value. Please provide more information about what you're actually doing.

Consider utilizing textwrap.dedent so you don't have leading whitespace for any of the lines:
import textwrap
import pandas as pd


def get_financial_summary(all_invest_df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
  return textwrap.dedent(f"""\
    Invested Amount: {(invest_sum := all_invest_df['Investment'].sum())}
    Payout Amount: {(payout_sum := all_invest_df['Payout'].sum())}
    Net Winnings: {payout_sum - invest_sum}
  """)


all_invest_df = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'Investment': [1000, 1500, 1200],
  'Payout': [1800, 2300, 1600],
})
print(all_invest_df)
print(get_financial_summary(all_invest_df))

Output:
   Investment  Payout
0        1000    1800
1        1500    2300
2        1200    1600
Invested Amount: 3700
Payout Amount: 5700
Net Winnings: 2000

